# How to download the mp3 file from webserver into my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have a list of mp3 files on server.

Now I want that when the user clicks the button the selected mp3 file should get downloaded into his/her iPhone.

How can it be done?

Any references to articles or tutorials related to this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the Techniques is using:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest
```

You can initiailize a URL Request as the following:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your server url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];

NSURLConnection *URLConneSync = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And the delegates of the NSURLConnection:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

#### Update

On RecieveData Delegate you can do as follows:

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager;
 [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"Your Path" contents:nil attributes:nil];

  NSFileHandle *FileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"Your Path Again"];
```

Note: you can get the iphone/iPad SandBox Path by using:

```
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *sDocumentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: How does this download the mp3 file?

Comment: you will need to create a new file on the delegate didReceiveResponse and Append the data on the file on the deleaget didReceiveData.

Comment: See : [NSFileHandle] (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hey but can you provide more code on what should be done on `didReceiveResponse` method?

Comment: @PARTH: Is there any progress regarding your issue?

Comment: @Ahmad: Sorry I didnt get time really to test this. Today I will test this out and get you a response soon!!

Answer (score 0):

check the [Simple URL Connections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245) code sample...
it explains how to get, put and post data to server....